# Gun terminology: is cylinder or chamber correct in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, differences

*We looked at each other like we had each just rolled a ***chamber*** in Russian roulette and now had the guns in our mouths.*

If the chambers are what's inside of the actual cylinder, which is what you spin, would "like we had each just rolled a **cylinder**" be more accurate?

Comment: you probably want “*spun the cylinder*”...

Comment: A 'chamber' is the part of a gun which holds a piece of ammunition. Revolvers are very specific guns which have a number of (incomplete) chambers drilled into a cylinder each of which can hold a piece of ammunition. As the cylinder rotates each chamber drops into place in turn becoming a complete chamber. If there is a bullet in the chamber the gun can be fired. Other weapons such as magazine loading rifles have a chamber but no cylinder the bullets being inserted into the chamber from the magazine clip. What you spin is the cylinder.

Comment: If the chamber is in the cylinder, then the chamber was rolled too.

Comment: Note that the verb here is *rolled,* not *spun.* You can spin the cylinder and have a chamber roll into firing position.

Comment: @WeatherVane no, the cylinder was rolled (or spun) the chambers merely had their positions changed by the rolling of the cylinder. If you spin a spoked wheel the spokes aren't spun, just moved because they are part of the wheel.

Comment: @AndrewLeach -Nkt sure how to interpret your comment.  The action performed in Russian Roulette is spinning the cylinder.  Right?

Comment: @Jim Yes. But the quote is talking about the chambers and uses the verb *rolled.* That's not incompatible.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - But it’s not idiomatic.  If I heard that i’d  roll my eyes and think, “This did not come from a native English speaker”

Comment: As a cylinder has (usually) six chambers, it would be difficult to spin **a** chamber - six spin. However, the normal object of to spin in Russian Roulette is a cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

> If the chambers are what's inside of the actual cylinder, which is what you spin, would "like we had each just rolled a cylinder" be more accurate?

Yes, "cylinder" would be correct.

> In firearms, the cylinder is the cylindrical, rotating part of a revolver containing multiple chambers, each of which is capable of holding a single cartridge. The cylinder rotates (revolves) around a central axis in the revolver's action to sequentially align each individual chamber with the barrel bore for repeated firing.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_%28firearms%29

Cylinders spin, chambers are part of the cylinder.

[image]
By Photograph by Rama, Wikimedia Commons, Cc-by-sa-2.0-fr, CC BY-SA 2.0 fr, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=12345217

Comment: I think this answer also needs to address the verb used (spin vs rolled) as well as the article (a vs the). Just saying, “Yes, cylinder is correct” is misleading.

Comment: @Jim The question asked which word is correct. Wouldn't "spin vs rolled" be a separate question?